# How to get the resource Uri of an embedded resource?

Tags: c#, .net, resources, xsd, mstest

How to get the resource Uri of an embedded resource?

I have a method as below which validates an xml against an xsd file. This method is used within an MSTest:

```
     public static string Validate(string xml, string relativeXsdFilePath)
            {
                var schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();

// relativeXsdFilePath like 'TestData.Xsd.XsdFile1.xsd'
                var schemaUri = ResourceHelper.GetPath(relativeXsdFilePath);

                schemas.Add("", schemaUri);

                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xml));
                string msg = null;
                doc.Validate(schemas, (o, e) =>
                {
                    msg = e.Message;
                });
                return msg;
            }
```

And I'm implementing the below method with no success so far!:

```
    public static string GetPath(string relativeFileName)
    {
        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName).Name;

         var resourceName = GetResourceName(relativeFileName);

// resource name would be like 'ProjectName.UnitTests.TestData.Xsd.profile.xsd'
        var result = string.Format("/{0};component/{1}", assemblyName, resourceName);

        return result;
    }
```

My XSD is located here:

```
ProjectRoot
---TestData
------Xsd
---------XsdFile1.xsd
```

Answer (score 3):

I realized it also accepts XmlReader so here is my solution if anyone will have the same problem:

```
 public static XmlReader LoadAsXmlReader(string relativeFileName)
        {
            var result = LoadAsStream(relativeFileName);

            var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(result);

            return xmlReader;
        }

        private static Stream LoadAsStream(string relativeFileName)
        {
            var resourceFileName = Assembly
                .GetExecutingAssembly()
                .GetManifestResourceNames()
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.EndsWith(relativeFileName));


            return Assembly
                .GetExecutingAssembly()
                .GetManifestResourceStream(resourceFileName);
        }
```

Comment: Quoting from MSDN: `In the .NET Framework 2.0 release, the recommended practice is to create XmlReader instances using the XmlReader.Create method. This allows you to take full advantage of the new features introduced in this release. For more information, see Creating XML Readers.` - [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cssfs8c4.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

As a quick simple solution:

```
public static string GetPath(string relativeFileName)
{
    return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames().FirstOrDefault(x => x.EndsWith(relativeFileName));
}
```

Comment: thanks but that just returns the resource name. It's not possible to add just the name to the schemas.Add() collection. it requires a full path.